# How to connect java application on one Computer with database on another Computer

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have developed a desktop java application and created its DB by using easyPHP. I have connected 2 computers with IP address `192.168.1.2` for the first one and `192.168.1.3` for the second one. Now I want to put the easyPHP on the first computer and the application on the second computer, but I have problem with the connection. The code which has been used for the connection is:

```
    public DataSource getDataSource(){ 
     BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource(); 
     ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
     ds.setUsername("root"); 
     ds.setPassword(""); 
     ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2/en_library"); 
     ds.setMaxActive(20); 
     ds.setMaxIdle(4); 
     return ds; 
    }
```

It gives me this error message:

```
    Feb 10, 2015 11:41:01 AM UserSearch.UserSearch <init> SEVERE: null
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
    PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
```

---

SOLVED:

I have done the following steps:

1- Open port 3306 from firewalls

2- Grant all privileges to my user through
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON en_library.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD`'

3- Change bind-address : 0.0.0.0

4- restart MySQL

5- In the connection URL write `("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/en_library")`

---

Comment: Is MySQL listening on the network interface? By default it is often configured to listen on localhost only.

Comment: what's the full stack trace?

Comment: Dear @ruediste how to make it listening on the network interface?

Comment: locate your mysql server configuration file (what OS are you using?) and check the value of bind-address. Set it to 0.0.0.0

Comment: I'm using 'Windows 7 32 bit' and changed bind-address to 0.0.0.0 @ruediste

Answer (score 1):

You should add more port, since `3306` is MySQL's default port, we have:

```
ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/en_library");
```

and remember put connection string snippet into a try-catch block.

Comment: Dear @dovy I have tried it but not worked !

Comment: @JavaCrawler, try disable firewall or open the port 3306 for MySQL.